# What defines a 'custom theme' in magento?

Tags: magento, plugins, themes, magento-1.7

I'm currently using a Magento theme I had purchased from themeforest and am wondering if that is defined as a 'custom theme' or not.

I am new to the magento system so I'm trying to find out which plugin option I require - the Custom Theme option, or not.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it there are 2 types of themes: **default** and **custom**. Default ones are already there. If you bought it from themeforest then it is custom.

But if it is a setting in your theme then it probably asks if you make changes to that theme.

Answer (score 1):

- Copy your theme folder in template/default
- Go to admin (system -> configuration -> design)
- And select your new theme
- If you want to set this theme on specific category or CMS page, then you need set it on custom theme, otherwise it should be selected through design.